# how to register click on a button without onclick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, event-listener

I have like 30 or so buttons in my react app. and i don't want to add event-Listener to each and every button. but every button has a specific job to do. So is there any way i can achieve this.

something like this(its depreciated now):

```
$("button").click(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/" + this.value)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setUser(result));
  });
```

Comment: If every button has a specific job to do, then... why don't you want to add event listeners to each one? How are you adding click listeners, that you find it so tedious?

Comment: While React doesn't do event delegation in the "normal way" (everything gets delegated to the document) you can still use it. Add one listener to the buttons container, watch for the clicks from the buttons which you may want to add some kind of data attribute to, and then that can be processed when you pass down your `handleClick` handler to the buttons.

Comment: Event Delegation is your answer

Answer (score 0):

I added the same class names to DOM elements which you want to add the event listeners and those elements by using getElementsByClassNames method.
Then, added the event listener to them.

```js
let count = 0;
function onClick() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerText = count++;
}
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-multiple");
[...buttons].forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", onClick));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple scroll example</title>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="clear-section" class="clear-section">
      <input type="button" value="V1" class="btn-multiple" />
      <input type="button" value="V2" class="btn-multiple" />
      <input type="button" value="V3" class="btn-multiple" />
      <input type="button" value="V4" class="btn-multiple" />
      <input type="button" value="V5" class="btn-multiple" />
      <input type="button" value="V6" class="btn-multiple" />
      <p id="count"></p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't want / can't (as per requirements)  add event listener to my app, so this way is out.
thanks for help..